PHP/CURL/simple-html-dom: Cannot retrieve or parse a webpage
The following code results in: "ERROR: The request could not be satisfied".
require_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
$url="https://www.ontario.ca/page/2024-ontario-immigrant-nominee-program-updates";
//$url="https://www.google.com/";
$base = $url;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201');

$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($str);
var_dump($html);

However, it does not have problems loading google.com.

Try var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl)); to debug. I bet there is some 403/Access Forbidden problem.

Yes, there is a 403. array(37) { ["url"]=> string(74) "https://www.ontario.ca/page/2024-ontario-immigrant-nominee-program-updates" ["content_type"]=> string(9) "text/html" ["http_code"]=> int(403) ["header_size"]=> int(380) ["request_size"]=> int(187) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(19) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.128671) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.062844) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.077464) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.114426) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(919)  ... Now, what can we do about it?
